# GCloud DNS, A and TXT record sets not being published?

Tags: dns, gcloud, recordset, google-cloud-dns

This is my first time using GCloud DNS, looking to configure a public zone for Hodl.Art. Opted for GCloud because their DNSSEC supports RSASHA256 (GoDaddy doesn't, nor the rest of my registrars), compatible with ENS.Domains for renaming a digital wallet.

My problem is that, try as I may, GCloud doesn't want to publish/make-public my A and TXT record sets. The zone currently looks like this in the console but no resolution!?

Am I overlooking something obvious or need to turn on some other functionality?

```
@.hodl.art. A   300 46.252.205.197
_ens.hodl.art.  TXT 300 "a=0x40974E5e819064c7159E2198E2ab540eE8C874bd"
hodl.art.   NS  21600   
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.
hodl.art.   SOA 21600   
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300
www.hodl.art.   CNAME   300 @.
```

Comment: I wonder whether there's an issue with the `@.holdl.art` A record? This may need to be a specific host. Can you explain what you did when you "try as you may"? What are you doing to confirm that these changes aren't public? I `dig _ens.hodl.art. TXT`.

Comment: Thanks Daz. I overlooked your comment. Quite right the issue was with the "@" part in which GCloud DNS will "fail" upon, as they dislike that syntax. Unlike other record-sets at GoDaddy etc, the field either needs leaving blank or * for wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `@` as the origin, for Google Cloud DNS leave the entry field blank.

```
hodl.art.   A     300 46.252.205.197
www.hodl.art. CNAME 300 hodl.art.
```

[Google Cloud DNS Managing records](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records)

Comment: Thanks John. I now see the documented entry  "Note: Adding the @ symbol in this field causes the record to fail.". I've switched the record to a blank field and hope that validates the record...

Comment: Whilst I'm not fully up and running, waiting for propagation/testing etc, records are now visible when previously failed, without any error reporting. I've Ticked John's solution as he was first to answer, even though Steven also gave a similar answer. Many thanks to you both.

Answer (score 0):

"To create a wildcard DNS record, enter an asterisk—for example, *.example.com.

Note: Adding the @ symbol in this field causes the record to fail."

---Google Cloud DNS Managing records---

Comment: Thanks Steven. As above, I just found that exemption too that GCloud fail the record if using the @ symbol, otherwise allowed at GoDaddy DNS etc. I'll leave blank for now and consider wildcards in the future. This would explain publishing/visibility issues even though the console says the record was processed.